# Why no torque along this axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, vectors, torque, gyroscopes

[image]

> Consider a gyrocompass consisting of a balanced spinning disk held in a light frame supported by a horizontal axle. The assembly is on a turntable rotating at steady angular velocity $\Omega$.  There cannot be any torque along the horizontal $A B$ axis because the axle is pivoted.

I'm not getting why there can be no torque along the axle due to it being pivoted ?

Answer (score 4):

Torque requires a force that is applied to a lever arm.  The quoted statement is saying that the gyroscope is free to rotate about the axis AB, meaning that no rotational force can be applied to it as long as it is free to rotate.  With no applied force, there can be no applied torque.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why " gyro is free to rotate about AB" implies " no rotational force can be applied to it ". Can you please explain it. Thank you

Comment: If you grip axis AB with a pair of pliers in an attempt to rotate it, it is no longer free to rotate, which violates the problem statement.

Comment: So you mean that the authors already assume that no matter what the motion be, the rotation around the axle is going to be free. And therefore there is no torque.

Answer (score 1):

With good bearings at (A) and (B), there would be no initial torque vector directed along the AB axis. But, in the situation sketched, there would be equal and opposite horizontal forces acting at (A) and (B).  These cause a torque vector pointing up. This would cause the angular momentum vector of the wheel to swing up, which would rotate the AB axis.  The axis of the wheel would stabilize in the vertical position with the wheel rotating in  the same direction as the platform. This configuration will not function as a compass.

Comment: Concerning whether this would work as a compass:  in a gyrocompass the axis AB is mounted vertically and the Earth is the "rotating platform".  This means that (as you note) the wheel will end up with its spin axis aligned with the rotation of the Earth, i.e., pointing north.  This is explained in more detail in Kleppner & Kolenkow's *An Introduction to Mechanics*, which also appears to be the source of the OP's diagram.  (Chapter 7 in the first edition — not sure about the second.)

Comment: Yes this is from K&K :)